# Is the nilpotency class well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying a book of group theory which defines these structures:

[image]

After that he states these two lemmas:

[image]

[image]

Just after to states and prove these lemmas the author says:

[image]

I used just one of these lemmas, see:

Suppose $$\{1\}=G_0\subset G_1\subset\ldots\subset G_n=G$$ and $$\{1\}=G'_0\subset G'_1\subset\ldots\subset G'_m=G$$ are two central series of $G$, then we have by lemma 1.5.14: $G_n=G\subset Z_n(G)\implies Z_n(G)=G$ and $G'_m=G\subset Z_m(G)\implies Z_m(G)=G$, then $Z_n(G)=Z_m(G)$ which implies $n=m$.

I would like to know if my solution is correct, I find this weird because I used just one lemma from above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct because $Z_n(G)$ is a well defined object for **all** $n$.  If $Z_n(G) = G$ then $G/Z_n(G) \simeq 1$ is it's own center therefore $Z_{n + 1}(G) = G$ as well.

So $Z_n(G) = Z_m(G)$ doesn't imply $n = m$.

Comment: Do you have any hint how to correct it? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Apply 1.5.14 to the lower central series and show that the length of the upper central series is at most the length of the lower central series.  Then apply 1.5.15 to the upper central series to get the reverse inequality.